# CILineOverlay Filter in ios

Tags: ios, filter, ios6

How to create CILineOverlay like filter in ios

i know it is available for Mac OS

but i want to create this filter on my ios App

is there any way to use the Mac os CILineOverlay filter in ios

like create the effect in Mac OS and use it as a library on ios

or any other way?

Comment: There is a open source library for this ["GPUImage Framework"](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#visual-effects), kindly try these 3 filters it may help you! 1) GPUImageCrosshatchFilter 2) GPUImageSketchFilter 3) GPUImageToonFilter